# cURL- how to get a response through commandline?

Tags: curl

i have a client requirement where i should submit an xml file with data and to recive the processed data through poll reponse.
i used curl to trasfer the file from commandline to http site.

```
curl -v -d @request1l.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf8" 
     http://**/ws -o request2.xml .
```

now to get the poll response into an xml what should i do?
which is the command used for this?

also how do i track the errors during the post or poll request?

i am very fresh to web technology and just understanding the things.

brgds
arun

Comment: Huh? I can't follow what you're saying.

Comment: I am having problems understanding your question also.

Comment: make it about libcurl as this is a programming site.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use -Ss to silence the stats and show errors. the return code from the call give you errors if they happen. Unless the site you are uploading to, returns an XML response, you will likely have to create one from the response code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`eval $(curl -s -X "PUT" -D - | gawk '$1=="GREP_VAR_HERE:"{sub(/\r/,"",$2); printf("VARIABLE_NAME=\"%s\"\n",$2); }')`